# can figure out why my win image wont show up after another player wins

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having trouble figuring out why it wont show the other player winning after one player wins.
When one player wins its supposed to say "player (1 or 2) wins press r to restart" but after one person wins it doesn't show the other players win tab.
here's the code it would take up a lot of the page so I use paste bin
https://pastebin.com/MaCnFChE
thanks to anyone who helps in advanced
NOTE-- its very sloppy I know I need to fix it lol

```
hi
```

Comment: You have `game_over == True` in your `pgame_screen` and `p1game_screen` functions.  That's a boolean expression that does not change `game_over`.  You need `=` not `==`.

Comment: By the way, any time you have variables like b1, b2, b3, b4... or x1, x2, x3, x4,... you need to replace those with a list.

Comment: ok thanks, also hoe would you write out those variables in a list, could you give an example?

Comment: thanks for saying to change the game_over part but it still dosnt change the player win

Comment: You need to add the code to the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Links to external resources tend to break and the resource may no longer be available in the future. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you mean for like future purposes? i didnt want to take up 332 lines of the page so i used paste bin but thanks for the suggestions @Rabbid76

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how your code could be reorganized to utilize lists.  I don't have your images, so I can't actually run this, and that means your original issue is probably still present.

```
import pygame as pg
 
pg.init()
HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 600
FPS = 60
BGCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
Moves = 0
game_over = False
player = True
x = [1000] * 18
y = [1000] * 18
wins = 0
green = (0, 255, 0)
black = (0, 0,0)
go, go1 = 1000, 1000
 
#wins text
font = pg.font.SysFont('chalkduster.ttf', 72)
def update():
    wins_ = font.render(str(wins), True, black)
    screen.blit(wins_, [560,647])
 
# create the game window and set the title
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption("Tick Tac Toe")
# start the clock
clock = pg.time.Clock()
 
#load game images
BG = pg.image.load('sprites/background.png')
Player_X = pg.image.load('sprites/X.png')
Player_X = pg.transform.scale(Player_X, (100, 130))
Player_C = pg.image.load('sprites/circle.png')
Player_C = pg.transform.scale(Player_C, (130, 130))
game_overimg = pg.image.load('sprites/game_over.png')
game_overimg1 = pg.image.load('sprites/game_over1.png')
 
#keeps track of board

b = [0]*9

def pgame_screen():
    global go, wins, game_over, go1, player_win
    go1 -= 1000
    wins -= 1
    game_over = True

def p1game_screen():
    global go, wins, game_over, go1, player_win
    go -= 1000
    wins += 1
    game_over = True

def win_check():
    global go, wins, player_win
    if not game_over:
        return

    win = 0
    if (b[0] == b[1] == b[2]) or (b[0] == b[3] == b[6]):
        win = b[0]
    elif b[3] == b[4] == b[5] or (b[1] == b[4] == b[7]) or (b[0] == b[4] == b[8]) or (b[2] == b[4] == b[6]):
        win = b[4]
    elif b[6] == b[7] == b[8] or (b[2] == b[5] == b[8]):
        win = b[8]

    if win == 1:
        p1game_screen()
    elif win == 2:
        pgame_screen()

    return win != 0
 
def restart():
    global b, x, y, Moves, game_over, player
    b = [0]*9
    Moves = 0
    game_over = False
    player = True
    #player_win == False
    x = [1000]*18
    y = [1000]*18

#change player
def player_switch():
    global player
    player = not player
 
 
#where mouse is clicked
def def_placement():
    global wins, b, player, x, y

    # Which box was clicked?

    col = -1
    if 45 <= mX <= 190:
        col = 0
        yy = 955
    elif 240 <= mX <= 375:
        col = 1
        yy = 765
    elif 410 <= mX <= 560:
        col = 2
        yy = 580
    else:
        return

    row = -1
    if 45 <= mY <= 190:
        col = 0
        xx = 928,950
    elif 240 <= mY <= 375:
        col = 1
        xx = 740,763
    elif 410 <= mY <= 560:
        col = 2
        xx = 757,590
    else:
        return

    # If the cell is occupied, skip.

    box = row * 3 + col
    if b[box]:
        return

    # Claim it.

    if player:
        b[box] = 1
        x[box*2] = xx[0]
        y[box*2] = yy
    else:
        b[box] = 2
        x[box*2+1] = xx[1]
        y[box*2+1] = yy

    player_switch()
    print(player)
 
 
run = True
while run:
    global SysFont
    # row 1
    screen.blit(BG, [0,0])
    for i in range(0,18,2):
        screen.blit( Player_X, [x[i  ], y[i  ]] )
        screen.blit( Player_C, [x[i+1], y[i+1]] )
    screen.blit(game_overimg, [go,go])
    screen.blit(game_overimg1, [go1,go1])
    update()
 
    for event in pg.event.get():
 
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_r:
                restart()
                print('restarted')
                go += 1000
                go1 += 1000
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not game_over:
            mX = event.pos[0] # x
            mY = event.pos[1] # y
            def_placement()
            mX = 0
            mY = 0
            if not game_over:
                win_check()
 
    clock.tick(20)
 
    pg.display.update()
# close the window
pg.quit()
```

Comment: Ok thank you tim roberts, i dont really know everything i should know and do wish to learn more so thank you for the example on how to change it into lists, thanks @Tim Roberts